# How to show normal date format in the table headers in grafana?

Tags: grafana

I have a following table generated with SQL query in Grafana.
[image]

I need to group data by date and that's why using a transformation called **Grouping to matrix**. But unfortunately it's converting my date into a unix timestamp.

[image]

Question: How to show human readable date format after this transformation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by converting a date into a string using concat function of mysql.

I changed the sql query from `select date from table` for instance, to `select concat('', date) from table`